# How to get a return value from a function called during an event?

Tags: reactjs

I have a function let us say test() which is bound to a onMouseEnter event. test() returns a value back which is the current position of the pointer. i want to use this in another part of my code, so i want to store the returning value in a variable, how do i do that.

```
<exampleComponent
   onMouseEnter = {(e) => test(e)}
/>

.
.
.

test(e) {
    .
   return <obj>
}
```

Comment: I guess you can store that value in the component state and then use it elsewhere in your code.

Comment: You have XY problem. You likely need to update the state of the component, and then you can decide whether you need to render <obj> depending on the state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, it's best to store it in the state and pass it to another component..

```
class otherComponent extends Component {
  state = { val: '' }
  handleMouse = position => this.setState({val: position})

  render(){
   return (
    <div>
      < ExampleComponent mouseFunc={this.handleMouse} />
    </div>

   )
  }

const ExampleComponent = props => {

 return (
  <div onMouseEnter={(e) => props.mouseFunc(e.target.valueOfPosition)}/>
 )
}

}
```

This is a fairly rudimentary way and without knowing what your component tree looks like, I'm sure this isn't an accurate representation. But the idea is that

1. you would set the state with a variable that will hold your position in a component (Parent here for example).
2. Then you create a custom handler for your event .. and pass on the function to your child component (in this function you set the state of where you need it).
3. and Listen on the event in the relevant component(in this case the child)

If this tends to get messy and you are passing props up and down components and lose track of them, that is the moment when it may be good to consider using a state management library such as Redux

Comment: I thought of storing the position in the state and passing to the next component, my question in that is whether my entire application would re-render or only the elements that uses the changed state would re-render because it is quite a large application and i don't want the entire application to re-render for a small change such as a change in mouse position.

Comment: So from the point of where your state is changed.. and any children underneath would be re-rendered.. (Essentially the highest component of your app that is changed will cause a ripple effect to all the children unless you manually alter it with `shouldComponentUpdate`